# How to check if some numbers are included within a comma separated numbers using jquery?

Tags: jquery, filter

How can I show only the li items that have a number that match the numbers inside the var with comma separated numbers, when the button is clicked, using jquery?

```
var numbers = "1,2,3,4,5,300";
```

HTML

```
  <ul>
     <li>1</li> <!-- should be seen on click-->
     <li>7</li> <!-- should not be seen on click-->
     <li>3</li> <!-- should be seen on click-->
     <li>9</li> <!-- should not be seen on click-->
  </ul>
  <button id="filter">Click me</button>
```

EDIT: the numbers inside the var are comma separated numbers

Comment: That's not a string. A string is enclosed in single or double quotes.

Comment: you may need a array `var string = [1,2,3,4,5,300]; `

Comment: Sorry, just edited, the var contains comma separated numbers

Comment: @Freddie that's not valid JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// it would be better to start with an array, but if you have to start with a string
var string = "1,2,3,4,5,300";
// use .split to convert it to an array of strings
var toInclude = string.split(",");

$(function() {
  // select all your li elements
  // if you have more ul elements on the page with more li's you might
  // want a more specific selector using a class and/or an id
  $("ul li").each(function(li) {          // loop through them using each
    var num = $(this).text();             // get the text in each element
    if (toInclude.indexOf(num) == -1) {   // check the array to see if there's a match
      $(this).hide();                     // if no match, hide it.
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <!-- should be seen on click-->
  <li>7</li>
  <!-- should not be seen on click-->
  <li>3</li>
  <!-- should be seen on click-->
  <li>9</li>
  <!-- should not be seen on click-->
</ul>
```

Comment: use jquery function `$.inArray()` will be better

Comment: @Phil  > The $.inArray() method is similar to JavaScript's native .indexOf() method in that it returns -1 when it doesn't find a match. If the first element within the array matches value, $.inArray() returns 0.

Because JavaScript treats 0 as loosely equal to false (i.e. 0 == false, but 0 !== false), to check for the presence of value within array, you need to check if it's not equal to (or greater than) -1.    see [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/)

Comment: @AlexLooksSoSad that's not a reason to use one over the other. You can also easily convert the result of `indexOf` to a boolean using `~`, eg `if (~array.indexOf(value))`

Comment: @AlexLooksSoSad: If you want to. I doubt it makes very much difference.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/450p8btg/)

All you need to do is loop through your `li` tags and do an array lookup of the `innerHTML` of each one. If it's not there, hide it.

```
var numbers = [1,2];

$("li").each(function() {
    var text = parseInt(this.innerHTML), inArray = false;
    for(var i = 0, len = numbers.length; i < len; i++) {
        if(numbers[i] === text) {
            inArray = true;
        }
    }
    if(!inArray) {
        $(this).hide()
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution without JQuery:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
function onClickHandler() {
    var numString = "1,2,3,4,5,300",
        nums = numString.split(","),
        ul = document.getElementById("list"),
        items = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        if (nums.indexOf(items[i].innerHTML) == -1) {
            items[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
    </script>
    <ul id="list">
        <li>1</li> <!-- should be seen on click-->
        <li>7</li> <!-- should not be seen on click-->
        <li>3</li> <!-- should be seen on click-->
        <li>9</li> <!-- should not be seen on click-->
    </ul>
    <button id="filter" onclick="onClickHandler();">Click me</button> 
</body>
</html>
```